# Emacs build & install without emacsclient

Tags: ubuntu, emacs, debian, desktop-application

When installing Emacs from source, I run `./configure` which generates some Makefiles, which in turn install Emacs along with emacsclient and a daemon(?) after running `make install`.

Is there a way to exclude emacsclient and daemon from the installation procedure and leave only Emacs itself?

I've checked the options available when running `./configure --help` and read the readme file and haven't found anything that could help

Thanks

**Edit:**
The problem is that it creates 2 separate desktop apps: *Emacs* and *Emacs (Client)*. And in my view it is not the best UX. I would rather have only one of them installed, preferably *Emacs*. Are there any other options apart from deleting the desktop entry file? The OSes are Debian 12 (Gnome) and Ubuntu 20.04

Comment: You can't remove the server feature without hacking on the source code, because that's just part of Emacs.  To remove `emacsclient` you could either edit the Makefile, or just delete the executable as a post-install step.  But why?  What harm is the presence of `emacsclient` doing you?  If you don't want to use it you don't need to -- I'm sure you have a large number of executables on your system that you don't use; what's the issue with one more?

Comment: @phils well, it is not an extra executable that annoys me, I don’t think having Emacs and Emacs (Client) desktop apps at the same time provides the optimal UX. I believe it should be only either Emacs or `emacsclient`. And I was hoping for an easy way to opt out from `emacsclient`, so make install and make uninstall would be consistent. Thanks for your input though!

Comment: Is your question about icons on your desktop?  You don't mention desktop icons in the question.  Whatever the case, edit your question so that it describes the specific problem.  If it's desktop related, make sure you describe your desktop system (and check for related tags to use).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you'll have to (a) manually remove the existing unwanted desktop files from your current system, and (b) delete the equivalent `*.desktop` files from the `PATH/TO/CODEBASE/etc` directory in the emacs codebase before you next `make install` Emacs.  I don't think there's any config option to pick and choose which of them get installed.

Comment: It seems to be the most reasonable option, thank you for taking a look into it!